# Using Velocity's WebappResourceLoader with Spring

Tags: spring, velocity

I'm trying to use Velocity to create an email template that is mailed by Spring's JavaMailSender class.  The resource loader that I decided to use to find the Velocity template in my web app is WebappResourceLoader which is located in the Velocity tool jar.

However, depending on how I use the WebappResourceLoader, I get either a NPE when the web app starts up or the template can't be found.

If I specify the init properties for the Velocity engine in my Spring application context I get the NPE.  My configuration is as follows:

```
<bean id="velocityEngine" class="org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryBean">
  <property name="velocityProperties">
        <props>
        <prop key="resource.loader">webapp</prop>
        <prop key="webapp.resource.loader.class">org.apache.velocity.tools.view.WebappResourceLoader</prop>
        <prop key="webapp.resource.loader.path">/WEB-INF/velocity/</prop>
        </props>
   </property>
</bean>
```

The stack trace I get when the app is starting up is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.velocity.tools.view.WebappResourceLoader.getResourceStream(WebappResourceLoader.java:145)
at org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ResourceLoader.resourceExists(ResourceLoader.java:224)
at org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl.getLoaderForResource(ResourceManagerImpl.java:641)
at org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl.getLoaderNameForResource(ResourceManagerImpl.java:624)
at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.getLoaderNameForResource(RuntimeInstance.java:1464)
at org.apache.velocity.runtime.VelocimacroFactory.initVelocimacro(VelocimacroFactory.java:159)
at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.init(RuntimeInstance.java:261)
at org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine.init(VelocityEngine.java:107)
at org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactory.createVelocityEngine(VelocityEngineFactory.java:251)
at org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(VelocityEngineFactoryBean.java:57)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1460)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1398)
```

To fix this I changed my application context to as below:

```
<bean id="velocityEngine" class="org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryBean" />
```

And then in the service class, right before the code to merge application data with the template (which is at /WEB-INF/velocity and named regemail.vm) I added the following code:

```
    velocityEngine.addProperty("resource.loader", "webapp");
    velocityEngine.addProperty("webapp.resource.loader.class", "org.apache.velocity.tools.view.WebappResourceLoader");
    velocityEngine.addProperty("webapp.resource.loader.path", "/WEB-INF/velocity/");
    velocityEngine.setApplicationAttribute("javax.servlet.ServletContext", "localhost:8080");
```

The app starts fine but when the email is going to be sent, I get the following error:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet default threw exception
org.apache.velocity.exception.ResourceNotFoundException: Unable to find resource 'regmail.vm'
at org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl.loadResource(ResourceManagerImpl.java:483)
at org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl.getResource(ResourceManagerImpl.java:354)
at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.getTemplate(RuntimeInstance.java:1400)
at org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine.mergeTemplate(VelocityEngine.java:370)
at org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine.mergeTemplate(VelocityEngine.java:345)
at org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplate(VelocityEngineUtils.java:58)
at org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplateIntoString(VelocityEngineUtils.java:122)
at com.mywebapp.web.service.RegistrationServiceImpl$1.prepare(RegistrationServiceImpl.java:60)
at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:353)
at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:345)
at com.mywebapp.web.service.RegistrationServiceImpl.sendRegEmail(RegistrationServiceImpl.java:65)
at com.mywebapp.web.controller.SignUpController.onSubmit(SignUpController.java:97)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

I'm using Velocity version 1.6.4 and Velocity tools 2.0.  Any help much appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Three years later, but here's another solution that does not require to adapt your Java code to pass the ServletContext to Velocity Engine.

Simply use **VelocityConfigurer** instead of **VelocityEngineFactoryBean** in your Spring Context file like this:

```
<bean id="velocityConfig" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityConfigurer">
    <property name="velocityPropertiesMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="runtime.log.invalid.reference"><value>true</value></entry>
            <entry key="runtime.log.logsystem.class"><value>org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.Log4JLogChute</value></entry>
            <entry key="runtime.log.logsystem.log4j.logger"><value>velocity</value></entry>
            <entry key="input.encoding"><value>UTF-8</value></entry>
            <entry key="output.encoding"><value>UTF-8</value></entry>
            <entry key="directive.include.output.errormsg.start"><value></value></entry>
            <entry key="directive.parse.max.depth"><value>10</value></entry>
            <entry key="directive.set.null.allowed"><value>true</value></entry>
            <entry key="velocimacro.library.autoreload"><value>true</value></entry>
            <entry key="velocimacro.permissions.allow.inline"><value>true</value></entry>
            <entry key="velocimacro.permissions.allow.inline.to.replace.global"><value>false</value></entry>
            <entry key="velocimacro.permissions.allow.inline.local.scope"><value>false</value></entry>
            <entry key="velocimacro.context.localscope"><value>false</value></entry>
            <entry key="runtime.interpolate.string.literals"><value>true</value></entry>
            <entry key="resource.manager.class"><value>org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl</value></entry>
            <entry key="resource.manager.cache.class"><value>org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceCacheImpl</value></entry>
            <entry key="resource.loader"><value>webapp, class, ds</value></entry>
            <entry key="class.resource.loader.description"><value>Velocity Classpath Resource Loader</value></entry>
            <entry key="class.resource.loader.class"><value>org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader</value></entry>
            <entry key="webapp.resource.loader.class"><value>org.apache.velocity.tools.view.WebappResourceLoader</value></entry>
            <entry key="webapp.resource.loader.path"><value>/WEB-INF/views/</value></entry>
            <entry key="webapp.resource.loader.cache"><value>false</value></entry>
            <entry key="webapp.resource.loader.modificationCheckInterval"><value>2</value></entry>
            <entry key="ds.resource.loader.instance"><ref bean="templateLoader"/></entry>
            <entry key="ds.resource.loader.resource.table"><value>templates</value></entry>
            <entry key="ds.resource.loader.resource.keycolumn"><value>code</value></entry>
            <entry key="ds.resource.loader.resource.templatecolumn"><value>content</value></entry>
            <entry key="ds.resource.loader.resource.timestampcolumn"><value>updated</value></entry>
            <entry key="ds.resource.loader.cache"><value>false</value></entry>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="templateLoader" 
    class="org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.DataSourceResourceLoader">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="yourDataSource"></property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass ServletContext object:

```
velocityEngine.setApplicationAttribute("javax.servlet.ServletContext", request.getSession().getServletContext());
```

Another option would be using `ClasspathResourceLoader` instead and putting your templates within classpath.

Comment: Thanks serg555.  According to the Velocity documentation, the ClasspathResouceLoader should be avoid when used from within a web app.  Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: @serg - it worked for me in a Jersey context, acknowledging that the ServletContext is injected through "@Context ServletContext context", and also that this *must* be setup before calling init(). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the documentation for [VelocityEngineFactoryBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/ui/velocity/VelocityEngineFactoryBean.html), you'll notice that there's a 'resourceLoaderPath' property that you can set. Given your configuration above, it looks like you've placed your Velocity templates under `/WEB-INF/velocity/`, so use that as the value for 'resourceLoaderPath' and the factory bean should load your templates just fine.