# configuring mail templates and metadata fields in java

Tags: java, email

I am working on one application which has lot of mailing logic depending on the workflow triggered by the user actions.

I am just wondering if there is any elegant way to store all metadata fields related to mail object (from mail id, to mail id, cc mail id, reply to mail id, subject, mail content) to database and map them with workflow ids. Also, all these fields could be picked up from logged in user's context object e.g.

from mail id - logged in user
to mail id - logged in user's friend
cc mail id - some mailing list
subject -  has sent you some sticker
content - hi , your friend , has sent you one sticker. Sticker id - .

Questions -
1. Is there any library/framework/utility which allows configuring all such fields?
2. Is there any recommendation on handling macro fields (enclosed within <>)?

PS - I have 50 such mail templates so velocity would not be a good idea. Moreover, velocity doesn't allow templates to be stored in database and I am clueless about how to configure to,cc,bcc mail address using velocity template.

Answer (score 1):

Velocity **is** a right tool, but it won't do it all for you.
Think about about a template like any view in MVC.
You need to supply the data (model) for it by yourself and connect the model with the template (view) with controller.

Regarding the database - spring has dedicated API for keeping templates in the DB. The official documentation ([Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#view-velocity), [Javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/velocity/VelocityConfigurer.html)) doesn't help much here, but see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21823816/2747533) for sample configuration.

Velocity has nothing to do with sending actual e-mails, use Java Mail API for that. You need to supply To, CC, BCC fields by yourself, but it shouldn't be hard thing to do.

Comment: Thanks for the response but this link doesn't say anything about pulling templates from db - http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/ui/velocity/VelocityEngineFactoryBean.html

Comment: Agree that the Javadoc (and neither Reference Manual) is not sufficient. I've provided the link to SO answer with sample DataSourceResourceLoader configuration.